# How can I run a batch script in 'Deployment Tools Command Prompt' (to make WinPE iso)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, winpe

I want to run a batch script inside of the deployment tools command prompt (part of the Windows AIK) to create a WinPE iso. I went through the steps to prep the media and created a script to navigate to the right directory and then run the oscdimg.exe tool.

The problem is that it runs in a normal command prompt, not the deployment tools command prompt. Is it possible to write a script that will run in the deployment tools command prompt instead of the regular command prompt?

My basic script:

```
@echo off
@echo Running OSCDIMG to create a WinPE amd64 iso in f:\OtherItems\view_stores\WinPE7\winpe.iso
f:
cd \OtherItems\view_stores\WinPE7
oscdimg.exe -n -bf:\OtherItems\view_stores\WinPE7\etfsboot.com f:\OtherItems\view_stores\WinPE7\ISO f:\OtherItems\view_stores\WinPE7\winpe.iso
@echo **********************************************************************
@echo Done.
@echo
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Properties of 'Deployment Tools Command Prompt' the target is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools\pesetenv.cmd"
```

So it's not a separate program, it's a batch run in the regular cmd prompt.

You can take the content of "pesetenv.cmd" and use it as a prefix to your batch:

Now the Deployment Tools commands should work as expected.

EDIT:
Scratch the above, I don't know why I thought that was doing something.  Adding the full path to oscdimg.exe and imagex.exe is what works for me.

```
C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\x86\oscdimg.exe -n -bf:\OtherItems\view_stores\WinPE7\etfsboot.com f:\OtherItems\view_stores\WinPE7\ISO f:\OtherItems\view_stores\WinPE7\winpe.iso
```

Comment: How is adding the full path any different than just running oscdimg without the fully qualified path? I'll play around with the pesetenv.cmd contents and see what I can get working, although it will be a couple days until I really have any time to do this. Thanks for your answer -- I'll accept it when I have some time to test it out =).

Comment: oscdimg.exe is not inherently understood in the environment.  If you type "choice.exe" in a Run box it's found because it resides in %SystemRoot%\System32.  If you copy all your AIK tools to the System32 directory, your original script will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but, I came across it recently looking for a similar solution.

I ended up using a PowerShell Script to create an extended batch file. You may need to slightly modify it for your situation / version.

```
param (
  $Path = "$PSScriptRoot\WinPE_amd64_PS",
  $IsoDestinationPath = "$PSScriptRoot\WinPE_amd64_modified.iso"
)

$devToolsPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools"
$inputFile = "$devToolsPath\DandISetEnv.bat"
$outputFile = "$devToolsPath\DandISetEnvCustom.bat"

if (Test-Path $outputFile) {
  $null = Remove-Item $outputFile
}

$null = Copy-Item -Force -Path $inputFile -Destination $outputFile
$null = Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Value ""
$null = Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Value ""
$null = Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Value "rem Custom Commands"
$null = Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Value "Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:`"$Path\media\sources\boot.wim`" /index:1 /MountDir:`"$Path\mount`""
$null = Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Value "Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:`"$Path\mount`" /commit"
$null = Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Value "MakeWinPEMedia /ISO `"$Path`" `"$IsoDestinationPath`""
$null = Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Value ""

Write-Host "Running script `"$outputFile`"."
cmd.exe /c $outputFile
```